# AWS Cluster autoscaler deployment keeps throwing error Failed to regenerate ASG cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-auto-scaling

I am trying to deploy ClusterAutoscaler on AWS EKS, having multiple nodegroups. The nodes are in public subnet and have internet connection from within. But the ClusterAutoscaler deployment( Multi ASG) keeps failing and the pods keep restarting with the following error.

```
I0323 14:09:02.441010       1 auto_scaling_groups.go:138] Registering ASG eks-2ab883a6-97e1-c240-5d22-5a87384ef2fe
I0323 14:09:02.441022       1 auto_scaling_groups.go:354] Regenerating instance to ASG map for ASGs: [eks-1ab883a6-97e6-5d39-89b2-ceaa807bd403 eks-2ab883a6-97e1-c240-5d22-5a87384ef2fe]
I0323 14:09:02.441602       1 reflector.go:123] Starting reflector *v1.StorageClass (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
I0323 14:09:02.441630       1 reflector.go:161] Listing and watching *v1.StorageClass from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
I0323 14:09:02.441956       1 reflector.go:123] Starting reflector *v1.Service (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
I0323 14:09:02.441973       1 reflector.go:161] Listing and watching *v1.Service from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
I0323 14:09:02.442239       1 reflector.go:123] Starting reflector *v1.ReplicaSet (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
I0323 14:09:02.442266       1 reflector.go:161] Listing and watching *v1.ReplicaSet from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
I0323 14:09:02.442478       1 reflector.go:123] Starting reflector *v1.Pod (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
I0323 14:09:02.442499       1 reflector.go:161] Listing and watching *v1.Pod from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
I0323 14:09:02.442710       1 reflector.go:123] Starting reflector *v1.Node (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
I0323 14:09:02.442725       1 reflector.go:161] Listing and watching *v1.Node from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
I0323 14:09:02.443103       1 reflector.go:123] Starting reflector *v1.PersistentVolume (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
I0323 14:09:02.443119       1 reflector.go:161] Listing and watching *v1.PersistentVolume from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
I0323 14:09:02.443379       1 reflector.go:123] Starting reflector *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
I0323 14:09:02.443394       1 reflector.go:161] Listing and watching *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
I0323 14:09:02.443652       1 reflector.go:123] Starting reflector *v1.ReplicationController (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
I0323 14:09:02.443669       1 reflector.go:161] Listing and watching *v1.ReplicationController from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
I0323 14:09:02.443881       1 reflector.go:123] Starting reflector *v1.StatefulSet (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
I0323 14:09:02.443901       1 reflector.go:161] Listing and watching *v1.StatefulSet from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
I0323 14:09:02.540405       1 reflector.go:123] Starting reflector *v1beta1.PodDisruptionBudget (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
I0323 14:09:02.540446       1 reflector.go:161] Listing and watching *v1beta1.PodDisruptionBudget from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:132
E0323 14:11:03.122943       1 aws_manager.go:259] Failed to regenerate ASG cache: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post https://autoscaling.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp: i/o timeout
F0323 14:11:03.122980       1 aws_cloud_provider.go:330] Failed to create AWS Manager: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post https://autoscaling.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp: i/o timeout
```

All the ASGs have the required tags for auto-discovery and I have tried the Cluster Autoscaler Auto Discovery deployment as well which also shows similar issue.

Comment: What is the version of the EKS cluster and cluster auto scaler?

Comment: CA Version : k8s.gcr.io/cluster-autoscaler:v1.14.7
EKS Version : 1.14 Platform Version eks.9 @franklinsijo

Comment: Also can you confirm whether the `aws-node` and `core-dns` versions are apt to the eks version?

Comment: `coredns`:v1.6.6
`aws-node`: amazon-k8s-cni:v1.5.5
These versions are currently installed on the EKS

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [EKS terraform module](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks) you just need to enable irsa by adding the following;

```
enable_irsa=true
```